# How do I disable GPU acceleration on Office 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, bsod, gpu

How do I disable GPU acceleration on Microsoft Office 2013? (This is causing my computer to blue screen.)

Comment: Why don't you find how to fix the blur screen?

Comment: @Ramhound Blue and chances are it's being caused by the GPU overheating.

Comment: the stop code on blue screen ?? usually GPU overheating get you freeze rather than blue screen, it hang, so it cannot display it.

Comment: @AntonyLee Your english is bad. On top of that blue screening for a GPU is quite normal. I had it bad when I was gaming on my desktop and forgot to turn the fans back on.

Comment: Ah, yes... Lets band aide the problem and **not** fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I dislike that a google search led me to the answer but this site seems to outline it quite clearly. [Follow these instructions](http://www.askvg.com/disable-hardware-graphics-acceleration-and-fix-blurred-font-and-cursor-hanging-problems-in-microsoft-office-2013/) and you should be fine.

"File" menu  in the ribbon , click on "Options". Click on "Advanced" tab , "Display" section You will find the  "hardware graphics acceleration"

[image: disable HW acceleration in Office 2013]