# My laptop shuts down when using Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: windows-7, laptop, microsoft-word, shutdown

I have **Lenovo ThinkPad W500**. Recently, it shuts off without any prior warning when I use **Microsoft Word 2013 64-bits**. I use many other software and this problem only happens **when Word is being used**. When it shuts off pushing the power button **will not** turn on the laptop. I have to remove the battery and unplug the power chord and put them back to be able to turn on the laptop. I took my laptop to a computer specialist and he put it under very intense test to see if it is shutdown due to overheat. It was **not** the case. I also called Microsoft but they did not have any solution at hand. I removed the Microsoft Office completely and installed a fresh copy of it. The problem persists.

Comment: Any warning/errors in the Event Log that match up to the time when this happens?  Have you ensured that all your drivers are on the latest revisions offered by the component manufacturers?  Try [disabling Word's hardware acceleration](http://superuser.com/questions/638992/how-do-i-disable-gpu-acceleration-on-office-2013) and test it like that for a bit, does it help any?

Comment: run a memory diagnostic tool such as [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).